# Is tornado.database asynchronous or not?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

Tornado provides a **tornado.database** wrapper to access MySQL database: 
[www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/database.html](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/database.html)

But in documentation I can't find anything about callbacks handlers for methods like **query()**. The same situation is for other methods **Connection()**, **execute()** etc.
So, is tornado.database realy asynchronous or not? If in my server application will be deadlock during MySQL query, tornado server will not be not available or not?

Comment: FWIW, the wrapper has been moved to its own project and is no longer actively maintained https://github.com/bdarnell/torndb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tornado database wrapper is not asynchronous, no.

Tornado was written to power FriendFeed, who decided that an asynchronous DB layer was unnecessary because they simply made sure all of their DB calls were extremely short.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asyncmongo based on mongodb as an asynchronous database.